# Search a forked repo in GitHub

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to search on github with search string  `@mozilla/togetherjs`. But it doesn't fetch any result. Is there any reason for this?

UPDATE:
GitHub mentions,

> To grab a list of a user's or organization's repositories, you can use the familiar **@user/repo** syntax.

For jquery(or any other repo) this works fine, but for togetherJS this doesn't show up any results.
Below are the two screenshots:

> for @jquery/jquery

[image: GitHub search for @jquery/jquery]

> for @mozilla/togetherjs

[image: GitHub search for @mozilla/togetherjs]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The repository `mozilla/togetherjs` is a fork of `simonwex/towtruck`. To include forks in search results, [you have to add a `fork:true` search filter to your query](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories#forks).

So, this should give you the results you want:

https://github.com/search?q=%40mozilla%2Ftogetherjs+fork%3Atrue&type=Repositories

Comment: Although the documentation on github indicates this is true, this doesn't seem to work anymore. any reference to `fork:true` seems to invalidate the search or at least return no results.  I tried including all my repositories, but same problem.

Comment: @MarioFlores I'm not seeing that behavior. For example, this still returns forks for me: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=togetherjs+fork%3Atrue&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults Can you share the URL you're using so that we can help you debug?

Comment: I reached out to github staff. `fork:true` does indeed work, but with a huge caveat: "our code search won't include most forks even with that argument. Unfortunately we aren't able to index all of the forks on GitHub at the moment." Github kindly flagged my fork of another repo to be indexed - continuing to prove they're an awesome company. 

Now, our team's non-technical staff could find the copy they're trying to edit without having to click through loads of yml files.

Answer (score -3):

Drop the '@'.  Just search for 'mozilla/togetherjs'.  More details at:

[Searching GitHub repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories)

Comment: Removing @ also does not help. I want that particular repository to come in results

Comment: Strange, I can find the repo you mentioned.  It shows up as a suggestion.  Are you searching from the GitHub main page or a specific repo/organization/account page?  Check the left of the search bar you might be searching just the repo you're on.

Comment: Yeah this is really strange. I have added screenshots to explain